# How can I check if an element in an array is equal to something in C?

Tags: c, arrays

My function is as follows:

```
bool checkWin(spaceleft)
{
     int i;
     int counter = 0;
     for(i=0;i<7;i++)
     {
         if(spaceLeft[i]==0)
         {
            counter++;
         }
     }
     if(counter==42)
        return true;
}
```

spaceLeft is an array from main. I keep getting an error regarding `spaceLeft[i]` that expression must have pointer-to-object type.

What should I do?

Comment: Which programming language do you talk about?

Comment: This is done in C.

Comment: Don't use [magic numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Use variables with proper names to hold specific values.

Comment: Since `counter` starts at `0`, and the loop goes a maximum of 7 times, could `counter` ever possibly reach `42`??  What does your function return if the `counter` is not `42`?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I made a mistake since I accidentally did 7 times 6 (another important number in main). It's supposed to be 7. @abelenky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify a ***type*** for the parameter of your function.
Likely types are `int*` or `char*`, but you haven't given enough information to perfectly deduce the type.

```
bool checkWin(/*You MUST specify a type here!*/ spaceleft)
```

Example: `bool checkWin(int* spaceleft)`